# How do I "join columns" so I can call $product->location

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following tables

**Events**

```
    id
    name
    start_date
    end_date
```

**EventLineItems** (belongs to event & product)

```
    id
    event_id
    product_id
    quantity
```

**Products**

```
    id
    name
    quantity
    rack
    section
    level
    position
```

Currently my blade for events.show file looks like this

```
@foreach ($event->lineitems as $item)
  <tr>
   <td>{{$item->product->id}}</td>
   <td>{{$item->quantity}}</td>
   <td>{{$item->product->name}}</a></td>
   <td>{{$item->resource_id}}</td>
   <td>{{$item->product->rack}} - {{$item->product->section}} - {{$item->product->level}} - {{$item->product->position}}</td>  
  </tr>
 @endforeach
```

I want to be able to call $item->product->location in my view instead of each field individually. I think this would go in my model as a function but not sure how or what to google.

For simplistic purposes think (invoice, lineitems, products)

Comment: would you please add your models to the post?

Comment: I made lots of edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how your DB structure is, but I assume that your Item model would **belongTo** Product. So below are examples using a lot of guess work...

So your `LineItem` model would contain.

```
function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}

function event()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Event::class);
}
```

Your Event model would contain something like:

```
function lineItems()
{
    return $this->hasMany(EventLineItem::class);
}
```

Then when you query the database using Eloquent, you would do something like:

`$events = Event::with(['lineItems', 'lineItems.product'])->get();`

This will get all events, with all the lineItems and the product associated with each of the lineItems

see https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations and https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading for further info

Edit based on updated question:

You can define an `accessor` in your model. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and‌​-mutators

```
public function getLocationAttribute()
{
    return sprintf('%s - %s - %s - %s', $this->attributes['rack'], $this->attributes['section'], $this->attributes['level'], $this->attributes['position']);
}
```

Then in your view, `{{ $item->product->location }}`

Comment: I edited my question, $lineitems belongs to an event and a product

Comment: Thanks, but I already get all my items and my blade file as displayed above WORKS however I'm looking for the DRY way of typing the last <td> as $item->product->location instead. I know the column doesn't exist

Comment: You want a way to get `$item->product->location`, but you know it doesn't exist?

Comment: so in theory `var location = "rack" + " - " + "section" + " - "  + "level" +  " - "  + "position";`

Comment: Well that's not really what you asked for in your original question, but take a look at `https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators` I will update my answer

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, in the beginning I wasn't sure what to ask or even what to google hence the confusion.